# 400 Bad Request: The SSL certificate error

Tags: ssl, nginx, openssl

I get this error when I try to get page with client key and certificate using this command:

```
curl -v -s --key /home/dmitry/Downloads/client_cert/client.mysite.key --cert /home/dmitry/Downloads/client_cert/client.mysite.crt https://mysite.com/api/login/
```

Here's what I see in nginx logs:

```
2014/12/08 06:30:55 [crit] 13087#0: *404 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:14094085:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:ccs received early) while SSL handshaking, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: 0.0.0.0:443
```

And here is part of my nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen  443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate     /home/mysite/conf/dev/ssl/com.mysite.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/mysite/conf/dev/ssl/com.mysite.key;
    ssl_client_certificate /home/mysite/conf/dev/ssl/com.mysite.crt;
    ssl_verify_client optional; 
    ssl_protocols       SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    server_name   mysite.com www.mysite.com;
    access_log    /home/mysite/logs/nginx_access.log;
    error_log     /home/mysite/logs/nginx_error.log;

    location /api/{
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_set_header SSL-client-serial $ssl_client_serial;
        proxy_set_header SSL-client-dn $ssl_client_s_dn;
        proxy_set_header SSL-client-verify $ssl_client_verify;

        if ($ssl_client_verify != SUCCESS) {
            return 403;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the commands I've used to create client cert:

```
openssl req -out client.mysite.csr -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout client.mysite.key
openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in client.mysite.csr -CA com.mysite.crt -CAkey com.mysite.key -set_serial 01 -out client.mysite.crt
```

What could be wrong here? Should I use some other certificate as CA for my client cert than server cert?

UPDATE:

When I do

```
openssl verify -CAfile com.mysite.crt client.mysite.crt
```

I get:

```
error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Comment: Looks like it might be solved by using a different Organization Name for the CA and Server cert: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47115211/3723760

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The certificate I used to sign another one was not CA so it simply could not be verified, so that's why I had this error from `openssl verify` command:

```
error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate
```

If you're not CA then obviously there's nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score 11):

First of all, enable debug log in `nginx.conf`:

```
error_log  logs/error.log debug;
```

And restart nginx. Then repeat the request and check the log file. Find the first line with `verify:0`:

```
2019/12/05 22:34:50 [debug] 5980#9776: *17 verify:0, error:20, depth:0, subject:"/CN=...", issuer:"/CN=..."
```

Here you see `error:20`. The error code comes from OpenSSL. [Here](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/include/openssl/x509_vfy.h#L113) you can find the constant name by code and [here](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/X509_STORE_CTX_get_error_depth.html#ERROR-CODES) the corresponding description by constant name.

Alternatively you can verify the certificate using `openssl` command line tool:

```
openssl verify -CAfile ca.crt client.crt
```

To verify it as the server sees it, `ca.crt` has to be the file listed in `ssl_client_certificate` or `ssl_trusted_certificate` directive in `nginx.conf`.

To verify the certificate on its own, `ca.crt` has to be the certificate that was used to sign `client.crt`. If it is self-signed, it'll be `client.crt` itself (`client.crt` will be twice in a row).

If you're getting `error 20` specifically and your client certificate is self-signed, you might have encountered [this bug](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/1418). To fix it you should either drop `keyUsage` from your certificate entirely or add `keyCertSign` to the list. To verify whether you've stumbled upon it, check whether Key Usage is listed in `X509v3 extensions:` section in the output of the following command:

```
openssl x509 -in client.crt -text -noout
```

Answer (score 1):

> ccs received early

Looks like a fallout from fixes for [CVE-2014-0224](https://www.imperialviolet.org/2014/06/05/earlyccs.html). Since patches [seems to be available](http://rt.openssl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=3400&user=guest&pass=guest) check that your system is up-to-date or report the bug to your distributor.

More details might be available if you would add information about the server system you are running, especially which OS, which version of OpenSSL and which patches.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-24-generic x86_64) and OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014. I installed openssl from standard ubuntu repo.

Comment: Are the problem restricted to curl or do you get the same problems with other clients (e.g. `openssl s_client`, wget) too? If only curl: which version you are running (`curl -V`). Could you do a minimal setup to reproduce the problem or create a packet capture for use with wireshark?

Comment: No, I also get the same error when I try accessing url from android mobile app.

Comment: If you want more help please create a way to reproduce the problem. Otherwise at least I will not be able to look at it at more detail.

Comment: I updated the question. There's something wrong with client cert

Answer (score 0):

In my case I mistakenly downloaded 'cloudflare.crt' file from digital ocean's website which has older certificate and that wasted quite a bit of my time.
As their tutorial shows up in the google search.

[wrong certificate from digital ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-host-a-website-using-cloudflare-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04)

[link to correct certificate](https://developers.cloudflare.com/ssl/origin-configuration/origin-ca)

Answer (score 0):

I have A nice working way. First before Creating pointing domain i.e

```
server_name api.example.com;
   location / {
        proxy_pass "http://example.com:9191";
    }
```

create a sub domain of api.domain.com in your cpanel then now locate your crt files here

> /var/cpanel/ssl/apache_tls/api.domain.com

you will find combined file done now put combine file   i.e

> ssl_certificate /var/cpanel/ssl/apache_tls/api.domain.com/combined;

then ssl you will find it under cpanel ssl/tsl->install ssl

> You can locate where your ssl file are via google

your end ssl configuration will be like this

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name api.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass "http://example.com:9191";
    }

    location /socket.io/ {

        proxy_pass "http://example.com:9191";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_read_timeout 86400;

    }
    location /engine.io/ {

        proxy_pass "http://example.com:9191";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_read_timeout 86400;

    }

    ssl_certificate /var/cpanel/ssl/apache_tls/api.domain.com/combined;
    ssl_certificate_key /var/cpanel/ssl/system/certs/crashgame/private.key;
}
```

> Please have your Private key in path where you can locate

Answer (score 0):

In my case i didn't fill subjects like ST OU O L .

when you create csr don't forget to pass "/C=UK/ST=LONDON/L=LONDON/O=Global Security/OU=IT Department" for example.

> openssl req -new -key $CLIENT.key -out $CLIENT.csr -subj "/C=UK/ST=LONDON/L=LONDON/O=Global